# javascript make falsey function param a standard value

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function and I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish what the following code does...

```
const func = (foo = defaultFoo) => {
  const f = foo || defaultFoo
}
```

Basically if the input parameter is **any** falsey value (not just `undefined`), I want it set equal to the default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> basically if the input parameter is a falsey value, I want it set equal to the default value

If you want **all** falsy values to become the default value including `0`, `""`, `null`, `false`, etc., that's pretty much what you need to do.

Note that there's no need for the default parameter given the first line of your function, since `undefined` is falsy. E.g.:

```
const func = foo => {            // No need for = defaultValue on this line
  const f = foo || defaultFoo
}
```

And yes, your use of `||` in that situation is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

You could omit the default value, because you check later too.

```js
const func = (foo) => {
    const f = foo || defaultFoo;
    console.log(f);
}

const defaultFoo = 42;

func();
func(undefined);
func(null);
func('');
func('foo');
```